# How can I destructure [object Object] in req.params

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am working on a MERN app, and want to pass an object from the client side to the server side.  The goal is to update the database with data collected in a form, but I also want to deconstruct the object being passed to work with the individual values.

The form collects a user's first name, last name, github user name and email address and stores them in state.  Here's how the object is defined and the initial call from the form component:

```
let obj1 = { developerLoginName: state.githubID, fname: state.firstName, lname: state.lastName, email: state.email }
API.getsync(obj1);
```

On the server side, in the controller file, req.params.id is [object Object], which should be the object being passed.  However, I can't access the object.  Deconstructing it like:

```
const { developerLoginName, fname, lname, email } = req.params.id;
```

results in values of 'undefined' for the variables.  I've tried to access this is various ways (parse, etc.) but can't get to the values.  How do I do this?

Comment: *"...which should be the object being passed..."* Apparently it isn't, because otherwise that would have worked. Perhaps you need to read some response body / use some middleware?

Comment: Have you tried just logging JSON.stringify(obj1) to see what's actually inside it?

Comment: `[object Object]` is a string representation of an object. Somewhere you're implicitly converting the object to a string (e.g. `{} + ""` is `[object Object]`).

Comment: what do you get if you `console.log (req.params)` only ?? can you try and use it to deconstruct

Comment: You sure you don't want `req.body`? `params` is usually for path parameters, eg `/path/:param`

Comment: It's better to include the code of  `API.getsync`.

Comment: can we see whats the actual value of req.params.id ?